# Android : Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

i am doing a ReactNative project and i got this error when i'm trying to access my local API (without httpS so) with ReactNative.
It works on iOS but not on Android.

```
2022-06-25 16:03:45.642 479-479/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2022-06-25 16:03:45.642 479-479/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2022-06-25 16:03:45.949 485-485/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2022-06-25 16:03:45.950 485-485/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
```

I think that i've tried to

- add `android:usesCleartextTraffic` in my Manifest
- Cold reboot
- Wipe data
- Create new avd
- Changing my mac DNS for Google's one

Nothing changed. When i launch `ENVFILE=.env.dev npx react-native run-android`, i got this error.

Should i build again before launching `ENVFILE=.env.dev npx react-native run-android` ?

I am a little bit stuck. What should i do ?

Comment: this is logcat...what is the runtime or build error

Comment: Yeah, looks like my /etc/hosts wasn't recognized and i had to change my API_URL var env into 10.0.2.2:8080.
I've had no errors on runtime